# c++: Inheriting a method with a different (but covariant) return type

Tags: c++, inheritance, covariance, return-type

Suppose we have 2 classes:

```cpp
class DataStructure {
public:
    DataStructure &operator=(const DataStructure &);
    friend const DataStructure &operator+(int, const DataStructure &);
    //...
};

class Array : public DataStructure {
public:
    Array &operator=(const DataStructure &);
    friend const Array &operator+(int, const Array &);
    //...
};
```

and we want `Array::operator=` and `Array`'s freind `operator+` to do the same thing as `DataStructure::operator=` and `DataStructure`'s freind `operator+`, except they should return `Array &`,`const Array &` instead of `DataStructure &`,`const DataStructure &`. I need to do it with dozens of methods, so is there a simpler way to implement it than the following?

```cpp
Array &Array::operator=(const DataStructure &other) {
    return (Array &)DataStructure::operator=(other);
}

const Array &operator+(int x, const Array &other) {
    return (const Array &)(x + (DataStructure)other);
}
```

---

**EDIT:** I came up with another idea, although it's a pretty bad one:

```cpp
class Array;

class DataStructure {
public:
    //...
    operator Array &() const;
};
//...
DataStructure::operator Array &() const {
    return (Array &)*this;
}
```

This way `DataStructure` is implicitly converted to an `Array` whenever needed, although it still can't handle correctly cases where both `DataStructure` and `Array` are legal but do different things, as in this example:

```cpp
//in class DataStructure:
public:
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,const DataStructure &)
    { os << "DataStructure" << endl; return os;}
//in class Array:
public:
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,const Array &)
    { os << "Array" << endl; return os;}
//...
int main() {
    Array x;
    cout << 1 + x << endl;
    // output: "DataStructure" instead of "Array"

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to find an answer. For `operator=`:

```cpp
class Array : public DataStructure {
public:
    //...
    using DataStructure::operator=;
    Array &operator=(const DataStructure &);
};
```

Writing only `Array &operator=(const DataStructure &);` would hide `DataStructure::operator=`, but with the `using` statement it only changes the method's return type.

*Note:* the `using` statement must precede the line `Array &operator=(const DataStructure &);`, otherwise `operator=` would be ambiguous.

---

As for `operator+`, the only solution I found is very problematic. It uses templates:

```cpp
public DataStructure {
public:
    template<class T> friend const T &operator+(int, const T &);
};
```

For instance, if the original implementation was

```cpp
const DataStructure &operator+(int x, const DataStructure &other) {
    DataStructure addition(other); /* in this example we assume
    *   that "DataStructure" isn't abstract */
    addition.someParameter += x; /* for simplicity, assume that
    *   "someParameter" is public/protected */
    return addition;
}
```

and we want to achieve the same result as in

```cpp
const Array &operator+(int x, const Array &other) {
    return (const Array &)(x + (DataStructure)other);
}
```

than we can simply write:

```cpp
template<class T>
const T &operator+(int x, const T &other) {
    DataStructure addition(other); /* notice that usually we would want
    *   to write "T" instead of "DataStructure", but sometimes it would
    *   give a different result */
    addition.someParameter += x;
    return (const T &)addition;
}
```

However, if there exists a function `operator+(int,/*const*/ ThirdClass /*&*/)` that has nothing to do with `DataStructure` or `Array` than we would have to change it, which might mess up the code. Luckily there are usually just a few friend functions, so implementing a new method that performs a conversion (as shown in the question) isn't so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is not good : the `operator=` should return reference to object of type Array, and should not be virtual :

```
Array &Array::operator=(const DataStructure &other) {
    DataStructure::operator=(other);
    return *this;
}
```

You can change `DataStructure` to use [NVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern) :

```
#include <iostream>

class DataStructure {
    public:
        DataStructure(){}
        inline virtual ~DataStructure(){}
        DataStructure &operator=(const DataStructure & other);
        inline friend const DataStructure &operator+(const int a, const DataStructure & other)
        { other.add(a); return other; }
        //...
    private:
        virtual void add( const int a ) const = 0;
    };
struct Array : DataStructure
{
    virtual void add( const int a ) const
    {
        std::cout<<"adding "<<a<<std::endl;
    }
};

void foo(const DataStructure &a)
{
    const DataStructure &b = 5 + a;
}

int main()
{
    Array a;
    foo(a);
}
```

Check [live demo](http://codepad.org/LaCMeP65). Then you have to implement the method `add` in your derived class Array.

---

To your edit :

Your new idea is an awful way of doing things in c++. What you do there is tell your compiler : "stop complaining, I know what I am doing". Also, it causing an undefined behaviour. It may appear to work, until you application starts crashing one day.

Comment: @stringQNA Your question looks like [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I don't see how it makes the code any shorter - I still have to implement 2 methods for any method that has `DataStrucure` in its return type. Also, in my original code (not presented here) `Array` isn't the only class inheriting from `DataStrucure`, so it makes more sense to implement the method's main operation in the base class `DataStrucure` and just convert the result in the derived classes.